Append Data to GitHub Release CSV File Using GItHub Action
I am trying to append data from a CSV file in my main branch to the end of a GitHub release file. Here is my .yml file:
name: Update Data and Release CSV

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  #schedule:
    #- cron: '0 0 1 * *'

jobs:
  update_data_and_release_csv:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4    

    - name: Remove existing release CSV if exists
      run: |
        rm -f test_request.csv

    - name: Download release CSV
      run: |
        curl -LJO **Current release file url**

    - name: Add release CSV to Git
      run: |
        git add test_request.csv
        git status

    - name: Check status before committing
      run: |
        git status

    - name: Concatenate census_data.csv and release CSV
      run: |
        cat census_data.csv test_request.csv > combined_data.csv

    - name: Check status after concatenation
      run: |
        git status

    - name: Commit Changes
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git add .
        git commit -m "Concatenate census_data.csv with release CSV"
        git push

    - name: Get release upload URL
      id: release_upload
      run: echo "::set-output name=upload_url::$(jq -r '.repository.releases[0].upload_url' <<< ${{ toJson(github) }})"

    - name: Upload updated CSV to release assets
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.release_upload.outputs.upload_url }}
        asset_path: ./combined_data.csv
        asset_name: combined_data.csv
        asset_content_type: text/csv
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

At this point, I keep getting this error:
Run git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Any help would be great!
I've tried a lot of iterations, but keep getting the same error even when it produces the combined.csv file.

Apparently, you don't have any changes. git status is isn't showing anything. You need to verify the steps before this to make sure there are changes that you want to push.
